# Pausing code execution till a button is pressed

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio

I'm trying to pause code execution till a button is pressed and this is what I came up with. I have not tested this but can anyone tell me if this is the right way to go about it? Button 'pressed' is active HIGH on the GPIO pin.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode (GPIO.BOARD)
#BCM uses the GPIO numbers while BOARD uses the actual pin number
GPIO.setwarnings (False)

while GPIO.input(17) == False:
    pass

print ("Button 1 pressed")

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: [Busy looping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) is the equivalent of sitting in a parked car with the accelerator held to the floor -- a bad thing unless necessary, which it isn't in this case -- you want the program to wait *idling*, by throwing a brief sleep inside the loop (for human interaction, say 0.1-0.25 seconds).  Otherwise it just checks the condition as fast as it can, likely hogging 100% of a processor core.

Comment: `I have not tested this` ... why not? ... that is all part of research that you should have done before posting your question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's one way of doing it - it will work. The better way is to use `GPIO.wait_for_edge(17, GPIO.RISING)` which will pause at that line until the button is pressed (on a RISING or FALLING edge).

However, BOARD numbering pin 17 is not a GPIO, it's 3V3.

You could also use GPIO Zero which is more intuitive (and uses BCM numbering):

```py
from gpiozero import Button

btn = Button(17)

btn.wait_for_press()
print("Button pressed")
```

You can use `Button(17, pull_up=False)` if it's pulled down, and the "pressed" state is relative to that.

https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: "wait for press" probably includes some [debouncification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch#Contact_bounce), a good thing since you very likely might end up having to implement it to some extent in the manual loop anyway, or else suffer the onoffonoffonoff chatter.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful. It should be 11 and not 17 since the board number is used.

Comment: @goldilocks There is hardware debouncing built onto my breakout board as described [here](https://hackaday.com/2015/12/09/embed-with-elliot-debounce-your-noisy-buttons-part-i/). Except in my case, the button and the 10k positions are switched making this active high. Nonetheless, I agree with you on the importance of debouncing.